# Can DatagramSocket Receive multicast Packets

Tags: java, android, udp, broadcast, multicast

I have a code that runs in a thread, which i use to send a DatagramPacket to broadcast address of each NetworkInterface in the computer and also to a multicast group. It is as follows:

```
try {
    String decl="Mymessage";
    DatagramPacket ackdp;
    while(true)
        {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        //First sending multicast (not broadcast) packet to a multicast group
        //231.26.179.75:37486
        ackdp=new DatagramPacket(s.getBytes(),s.length(),multicastGroup,port);
        BroadcastSocket.send(ackdp);
        //Now sending same message to broadcast address of each of the n/w interfaces
        Enumeration nwInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while(nwInterfaces.hasMoreElements())
                {
                NetworkInterface ni=(NetworkInterface) nwInterfaces.nextElement();
                if(ni.isLoopback()||!ni.isUp())
                        continue;
                for(InterfaceAddress ifa:ni.getInterfaceAddresses())
                        {
                        InetAddress broadcastIP=ifa.getBroadcast();
                        if(broadcastIP==null)
                                continue;
                        ackdp=new DatagramPacket(s.getBytes(),s.length(),broadcastIP,port);
                        BroadcastSocket.send(ackdp);
                        //port is same here :37486 (ip varies with network interface)
                        }
                }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
```

**My question is:** Can i receive both (multicast and broadcast) packets using same DatagramSocket? Note that both are sent to same port. Should i open a MulticastSocket or a DatagramSocket at the port 37486 to receive both packets?

**(Packets are send from PC but received on Android)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can `DatagramSocket` receive multicast Packets

No, because it can't join the multicast group.

You didn't ask, but for completeness:

> Can `DatagramSocket` send multicast Packets

Yes.

> Can `MulticastSocket` receive datagram (non-multicast) packets

Yes.

Comment: I want to receive both broadcast packets and the multicast packets to a group. How can i receive both packets in same multicastsocket.(both are sent to same port)

Comment: With a `MulticastSocket`. I said so. You said it yourself.