# How To Determine If a Received Packet Was Broadcasted?

Tags: java, udp, broadcast

After broadcasting a packet, the response address is my own (not x.x.x.255 as I expected).  How can I differentiate whether a packet was sent directly to me or broadcasted?  Of course in when *I* broadcast, I can infer if it was.

But when another device sends data, I can't figure out how to tell.  Wireshark can tell, but I know they do a lot of low level stuff.  Is this possible in Java?

Comment: How are you receiving the packets? A `MulticastSocket`?

Comment: `DatagramSocket`, I wasn't aware of MulticastSocket.  I'll go look at that now

Comment: My understanding is that a `DatagramSocket` can receive _only_ unicast packets, while a `MulticastSocket` can receive unicast and multicast. But they both just `receive` a `DatagramPacket`. Don't know if that helps you.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40210051/7852370

Comment: The DatagramSocket is receiving broadcasts just fine; I'm not multicasting.  However, I tried MulticastSocket and it's behaving the same way.